# Finding the diode ID and VD in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image: circuit]

I was asked to find the ID and VD in this circuit. The Vknee = 0.7V , Vin = 5 V and R = 1000 ohms.

I just wanted to make sure I'm understanding how to solve this correctly, so what I've done is:

1. Vin = 5 V, so Vin > Vknee and the diode should be on. Therefore, VD = 0.7 V.
2. ID = (Vin - VD) / R
3. ID = (5 V - 0.7 V) / (1000 ohms)
4. ID = 0.0043 A --> ID = 4.3 mA

Final answers being ID = 4.3 mA and VD = 0.7 V. Is this the right process to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. That  is correct. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's make a mathematical closed solution. I know that this is maybe above the OP's knowledge, but I think it is important to show it in combination with the other answers given.

---

The [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation), gives the relation between the voltage across and the current through a diode:

$$\text{I}_\text{D}=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_\text{D}}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{V}_\text{D}=\frac{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}{\text{q}}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\text{I}_\text{D}}{\text{I}_\text{S}}+1\right)\tag1$$

Where \$\text{I}_\text{D}\$ is the diode current, \$\text{I}_\text{S}\$ is the reverse bias [saturation current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_current), \$\text{V}_\text{D}\$ is the voltage across the diode, \$\text{q}\$ is the [electron charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge), \$\text{k}\$ is the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant), \$\text{T}\$ is the temperature and \$\eta\$ is the ideality factor.

So, for your case we can see that:

$$\text{V}_\text{source}=\text{V}_\text{D}+\text{V}_\text{R}\tag2$$

Using [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can see that:

$$\text{V}_\text{R}=\text{I}_\text{R}\cdot\text{R}\tag3$$

Because the diode and resistor are in series we know that:

$$\text{I}:=\text{I}_\text{D}=\text{I}_\text{R}\tag4$$

So, we get:

$$\text{V}_\text{source}=\frac{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}{\text{q}}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\text{I}}{\text{I}_\text{S}}+1\right)+\text{I}\cdot\text{R}\tag5$$

Now, we can solve \$(5)\$ for \$\text{I}\$ and plug it into \$(1)\$ in order to find the voltage across the diode.